# determinant of the hadamard inverse of a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ be a positive definite matrix with $a_{ij}>0$ for all $i, j$. Define the Hadamard inverse $A^{\circ -1}$ of $A$ as $(a_{ij}^{-1})_{i,j=1}^n$. Is it possible to decide whether $\det A^{\circ -1}$ is positive or negative?

Comment: The body asks for the determinant of the inverse, but the title asks for the determinant of the product of the matrix and the inverse. Please edit for consistency.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Not any more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. There are $4\times4$ examples of positive definite symmetric matrices where the determinant of the Hadamard inverse is negative and examples where it is positive.

For the first type, take a $4\times4$ matrix that with all entries 1, and replace the main diagonal with 100's.

For the second type, start with the above and then replace the "anti-diagonal" (the entries (1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1)) with 1/100.

Of course you can still decide if the determinant is positive or negative by computing it.

Comment: Is your second type positive definite? Doesn't it have a negative determinant?

Comment: It still has the 100's on the main diagonal

Comment: OK, I missed that.

Comment: but the second matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: @IshaGarg: If the second matrix were required to be positive definite, it would automatically have a positive determinant and the question would be moot.

Comment: @Anthony Quas: by second matrix, i want to say the second type in example given by you.

Comment: I know that the matrix A∘−1 in this case is neither positive definite nor negative definite. I want to  check if according to order of matrix it follows certain sign pattern.